# $query = http_build_query($params); $auth_hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $query, $secret_key);

Tags: python, php, hashlib

I have this php api request example I want to convert to python

```
function sendRequest($url, $params, $apiKey, $secretKey) {
$query = http_build_query($params);
$params['api_key'] = $apiKey;
$params['auth_hash'] = hash_hmac('sha512', $query, $secretKey);
$params['nonce'] = explode(' ', microtime())[1];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;}
```

And this is my python code but it keep returning incorrect hash, please how can I make this request in python?

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import time

params = {
   'name':'Matthew Jackson',
   'state':'nj',
   'zip':'034572',
   'address':'14 Main Street',
   'phone':'',
   'dob':''}

def request_ss( url, params,  api_key, secretKey):
    tosign = "&".join( [i + '=' + params[i] for i in params] )
    secretKey = str.encode(secretKey)
    tosign = str.encode(tosign)
    sign = hmac.new(secretKey, tosign , hashlib.sha512)

    res_body = {
       'api_key': api_key,
       'auth_hash': sign.hexdigest(),
       'nonce':  str(time.time())}

    r = requests.post(url, data=res_body)
    return r.text

create_url = 'api_url'
res = request_ss(create_url,params,api_key, api_secret)
print(res)
```

This code keep returning wrong hash from the server, I don't know if am right or wrong on the way I coded this on python, The goal is just to make a request and get the data from the server, the API provider only give the request example in php in which I don't understand.  Your support is going to be highly appriciated

Comment: A question title should be a very brief explanation of the question, not just some random code.